# Javascript regex accepting not-supposed-to-be-accepted inputs unlike in Java

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm familiar with Java regex but not Javascript regex.

I want to check the validity of the string input if it looks like a first name. A first name can either be xxxx xxx or xxx where x is a letter. Note that in what I've said, the number of x's vary. So here's my code:

```
function checkName(name) {
     var pattern = new RegExp('([A-Za-z]+|[A-Za-z]+\\s[A-Za-z]+)');
     return pattern.test(name);
}
```

I've made a function that will process the name from the text input in my form. Now it is working for inputs such as Michael or Michael James. However, it also works on M3 for example which has a number and is supposed to be not working. So any help on this one experts out there in the world?

Comment: Maybe you just want to ensure a whole string matches the pattern? Add `^` at the start and `$` at the end. Try `var pattern = /^([A-Za-z]+|[A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]+)$/;`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes that's what I want! Hahaha thank you sir. I don't know that yet but now I know. I'm familiar with Java regex but not Javascript regex. Thank you again! :)

Comment: @JudeMaranga Also, I think the below expression is more optimal:
`^[A-Za-z]+(\\s[A-Za-z]+)?$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `matches` method in JavaScript (unlike Java). If you just want to ensure a whole string matches the pattern,  add `^` at the start and `$` at the end.  Also, it is advised to use a regex literal notation `/.../` if your regex pattern is static.

Use

```
var pattern = /^([A-Za-z]+|[A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]+)$/;
              ^^                                ^
```

To further optimize it (although the performance gain will be tiny), you may use an optional group `(?:....)?` (see [vasan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1315419/vasan)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39228289/javascript-regex-code-accepting-not-supposed-to-be-accepted-inputs?noredirect=1#comment65794064_39228289)):

```
var pattern = /^[A-Za-z]+(?:\s[A-Za-z]+)?$/;
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kT5fI2/1).

```js
function checkName(name) {
     var pattern = /^([A-Za-z]+|[A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]+)$/;
     return pattern.test(name);
}

let log  = document.querySelector("#log"),
    test = document.querySelector("#test");

test.addEventListener("input", e => {
  if(checkName(test.value)){
    log.style.color = "green";
    log.innerHTML = "Passed!";
  }else{
    log.style.color = "red";
    log.innerHTML = "Failed";
  }
});
```

```css
#test:focus{outline: none;}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test" autofocus /><br />
<span id="log"></span>
```

Comment: And you're usually so good at marking duplicates...

Comment: What's the : for?

Comment: @torazaburo: I answered because OP comes from Java, actually. The fact that the Java `String#matches()` is not present in JavaScript made me post an answer.

Comment: @JudeMaranga: The `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group that only groups subpatterns without storing a captured value in the group buffer. The `?` is a quantifier matching 1 or 0 occurrences of the quantified subpattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Okaay thanks! Btw, one last question (though this is not really directly related to the post). This rule, the one adding ^ at the beginning and $ in the end, is this true to PHP regex too, if in any case you know?

Comment: In PHP, for validation reasons, I'd use `\A` instead of `^` and `\z` instead of `$`. In PHP, you need the anchors, as there is no Java-like `String#matches` either

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But that basically means the same? Or are they even necessary in PHP regex to achieve the same goal as I have in my problem?

Comment: `$` in PHP may match before the final newline, use `\z` instead. They are necessary to anchor the match at the start/end position.